# Is it possible to use statements in pattern matching branch?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to have statements in pattern matching branch?

I tried this, but it doesn't work. Maybe there is some special syntax for achieving this?

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5i;

    match x {
        1 => println!("one"),
        _ => println!("something"); // error: expected one of `,`, `}`, found `;`
             println!("else"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want multiple statements you have to use `{}`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5i;

    match x {
        1 => println!("one"),
        _ => {
            println!("something");
            println!("else")
        }
    }
}
```