Migrating from BASIC to Rust, what do I do with On Gosub?
Most BASIC to Rust code is straightforward. However, what do I do with On Gosub? My brief is to use identical code constructs wherever possible.
Here is the BASIC code (reduced to the minimum).
choice = 3
On choice GoSub labela, labelb, labelc
Print "End"
End

labela:
Print "choice a"
Return

labelb:
Print "choice b"
Return

labelc:
Print "choice c"
Return

Here is what I've done in Rust.
fn main() {
    let subroutines: Vec<fn()> = vec![labela, labelb, labelc];
    let choice = 2;
    if let Some(subroutine) = subroutines.get(choice - 1) {
        subroutine();
    } else {
        panic!();
    }
    println!("End");
}

fn labela() {
    println!("choice a");
}

fn labelb() {
    println!("choice b");
}

fn labelc() {
    println!("choice c");
}

The code is clumsy, worse than the original. I also need to address On Goto constructs, preferably in a uniform way. Can you help?

gosub and goto are really bad constructs. Flexible? Yes. Prone to human mistakes? Always. Learning the alternatives will lead you to more robust code, especially when it comes to unit testing.  For example; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804275/are-there-traditional-style-switch-statements-in-rust

GoSub is a normal procedure call with no parameters. What's bad about it?

You did everything right.  There is a zero element in Basic arrays, but it is not usually used. I would do this: vec![None, labela, labelb, labelc] and that: subroutines.get(choice).

Thanks for mentioning the zero element and suggesting None, @konstantin

@matbailie, I agree that goto is a bad construct. With such programs I take a data-driven approach as they invariably make poor use of global variables.

let Some(x) = foo.get(i) else { panic!() } is usually written as let x = foo[i].

Insofar as you're starting with working, rather than broken, code -- this question is probably better suited to [codereview.se] rather than Stack Overflow. You got an answer this time, but in general "best practice" questions tend to be closed as overbroad, opinion-based, or otherwise off-topic here.

You have translated the On Gosub to rust correctly.  Is it idiomatic? Probably not. The more common way in rust would likely be  switch / case :
match choice{
  1=>subroutines[labela],
  2=>subroutines[labelb],
  3=>subroutines[labelc]
  _=>println!("Unknown choice"),
 }

However that has the disadvantage of losing the arbitrary indexing capability. It will become unwieldy with any larger sets of options.
